# Data validation with custom directive before user inputs smth

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to validate data on my form using my own directive, but the data is validated only after user inputs something not right after binding.

```
myApp.directive('dvCyrillic', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        var CYRILLIC_REGEX = /^[а-яё -]+$/i;
        if (CYRILLIC_REGEX.test(viewValue) || viewValue.length == 0) {
          // it is valid
          ctrl.$setValidity('cyrillic', true);
          return viewValue;
        } else {
          // it is invalid, return undefined (no model update)
          ctrl.$setValidity('cyrillic', false);
          return undefined;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/n_canter/HB7LU/217/).
How can I validate data before user inputs smth?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angularjs initial form validation with directives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17011288/angularjs-initial-form-validation-with-directives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$parsers` will only validate from the View to the Model while the `$formatters` will validate from the Model to the View. You can refactor your validation in a separate method and add your validation to both the parsers and formatters:

```
var CYRILLIC_REGEX = /^[а-яё -]+$/i;
ctrl.$parsers.unshift(validate);
ctrl.$formatters.unshift(validate);

function validate(viewValue) {
  if (CYRILLIC_REGEX.test(viewValue) || viewValue.length == 0) {
    // it is valid
    ctrl.$setValidity('cyrillic', true);
    return viewValue;
  } else {
    // it is invalid, return undefined (no model update)
    ctrl.$setValidity('cyrillic', false);
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/219/)